# How to insert image directly into the database (php)?

Tags: php, html, image

I know it is not recommended, but I need to insert an image directly into the msql database.

The field is already like a blob

**Code: insert**

```
 public function insert($tableName, array $data){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $tableName (".implode(',', array_keys($data)).")
        VALUES (".implode(',', array_fill(0, count($data), '?')).")"
    );
    try{
        $stmt->execute(array_values($data));
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("[".$e->getCode()."] : ". $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Code: data**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) and $_REQUEST['submit']!=""){
extract($_REQUEST);
    $userCount  =   $db->getQueryCount('tb_user','id');
    if($userCount[0]['total']){
           $Photo = $_FILES['in_Photo'];
           $contentFile = file_get_contents($in_Photo['tmp_name']);
        $data = array(
                'C_Imagem'=>$contentFile,
                'C_user'=>$in_Name,
        );
        $insert =   $db->insert('tb_cruds',$data);
        if($insert){
            header('location:index.php?msg=ras');
            exit;
        }else{
            header('location:index.php?msg=rna');
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?msg=dsd');
        exit;
    }
```

}

**Code: Html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Photo</label>
    <input class="" type="file" name="in_Photo" id="in_Photo"   />
</div>
```

Comment: Why do what is not recommended since you know it is not? I would advice you save the images to a folder and save their names and may be paths if required. That way, you have less load on your database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31771193/231316

Comment: How to do storing in array, in this case the array is $data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Change collation of your database => utf8mb4_general_ci
2. File size should be accordingly
        TEXT can store 65,535 characters (approx 64KB)
        MEDIUMTEXT = 16,777,215 characters (approx 16 MB) 
        LONGTEXT = 4,294,967,295 chars (approx 4GB)
        VARCHAR can store upto 255 chars